# jQuery Plugin for Image Gallery/Full Screen (with thumbnails)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, image-gallery

I am searching for a jQuery plugin, or another JS library if needs be, which has functionality similar to this:

http://www.yoox.com/item.asp?cod10=34249005&tskay=768BABE2

When you click on the large image, it opens a full screen popup of the image.

Does anyone know of such gallery plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the lightbox plugin?

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 0):

**check it out:** full-screens any image on click.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("img").click( function(){
        this.requestFullscreen();
    });
});
```